# How to build a one-click mobile application deployment on Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play, fastlane

I am building a web application allowing users to build and deploy a Flutter mobile app on Play Store with one click.

I was testing the deployment with Fastlane when I got this

```
:~/data/60e294c76bb64b00207a83bc/android$ fastlane supply --aab ../build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab --track beta --rollout 0.5
[✔]  
[17:13:56]: fastlane detected a Gemfile in the current directory
[17:13:56]: However, it seems like you didn't use `bundle exec`
[17:13:56]: To launch fastlane faster, please use
[17:13:56]: 
[17:13:56]: $ bundle exec fastlane supply --aab ../build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab --track beta --rollout 0.5
[17:13:56]: 
[17:13:56]: Get started using a Gemfile for fastlane https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/#use-a-gemfile

+---------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|                                Summary for supply 2.187.0                                |
+---------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| aab                             | ../build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab    |
| track                           | beta                                                   |
| rollout                         | 0.5                                                    |
| package_name                    | com.draft.mobile.fosso_mael_elvis.p60e294c76bb64b0020  |
|                                 | 7a83bc                                                 |
| release_status                  | completed                                              |
| json_key                        | ~/Draft/pc-api-xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxwwwwyyy.json                  |
| skip_upload_apk                 | false                                                  |
| skip_upload_aab                 | false                                                  |
| skip_upload_metadata            | false                                                  |
| skip_upload_changelogs          | false                                                  |
| skip_upload_images              | false                                                  |
| skip_upload_screenshots         | false                                                  |
| validate_only                   | false                                                  |
| check_superseded_tracks         | false                                                  |
| timeout                         | 300                                                    |
| deactivate_on_promote           | true                                                   |
| ack_bundle_installation_warning | false                                                  |
+---------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+


[!] Google Api Error: Invalid request - Package not found: com.draft.mobile.fosso_mael_elvis.p60e294c76bb64b00207a83bc.
```

I got the error **[!] Google Api Error: Invalid request - Package not found: com.draft.mobile.fosso_mael_elvis.p60e294c76bb64b00207a83bc.** many times after many configurations from **fastlane deploy** to **fastlane supply**

It seems like this error means that to use Fastlane for auto-deployment you must deploy it first manually so that the package ID will be available in Play Store for an update. So it's almost like an auto-update that an auto-deployment

So my question is, is there a tool or a way to deploy a mobile application completely automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Try upload .aab or .apk manually on google play console, then use fastlane to auto deploy next versions...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of proposing a clarification experiment instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).